# Trying to use cloud storage on Db2 external tables

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I try to use Db2 external tables, with Swift or Amazon S3 object storage option.
I use my own Openstack Swift server.

Here are the details of steps:

```
[i1156@lat111 ~]$ swift --auth-version 3 --os-auth-url http://myip:5000/v3 --os-project-name myproject --os-project-domain-name default  --os-username user1 --os-password mypass list container1
outfile

[i1156@lat111 ~]$ db2 "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TB_EXTERNAL(COL1 VARCHAR(5)) USING (FORMAT TEXT DELIMITER '|' QUOTEDVALUE DOUBLE CCSID 1208 NULLVALUE 'NULL' NOLOG TRUE DATAOBJECT 'outfile' SWIFT ('http://myip:5000/v3', 'user1', 'mypass', 'container1'))"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

[i1156@lat111 ~]$ db2 "select * from TB_EXTERNAL"
COL1
-----
SQL20569N  The external table operation failed due to a problem with the
corresponding data file or diagnostic files. File name: "outfile". Reason
code: "1".  SQLSTATE=428IB
```

The result is the same when I try to use AWS S3 storage. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What Db2 version and platform? What is in the Db2 diag log?

Comment: I work with the last Db2 V11.5 FP8. I found what is going wrong with Swift: it seems that it is not working with the Swift V3 version. I changed the server configuration to the old V1 Swift version, and it works perfectly (after re-creating the external table with appropriate values). Maybe there is something to improve on Db2 side for make it working with the Swift V3 version (or maybe I missed something for the V3 version)? Now I'm going to make progress on the S3 case!